# Variation and functional derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $F$ be a functional on a certain space of functions (actually I don't know what's necessary to define functional derivative). Is the following equality true for any small variation $\delta f(x)$ ?
\begin{align*}
\delta F[f(x)]:&=F[f(x)+\delta f(x)]-F[f(x)]\\
&=\int dx\,\delta f(x) \frac{\delta F}{\delta f}(x)+\mathcal{O}(\|\delta f\|^2)
\end{align*}
If the variation is denoted as $\epsilon \phi(x)$ with $\epsilon\to 0$, it's easy to see. However, I don't know how to deal with an arbitrary variation.

Comment: It depends on the definition on functional derivative. What is your definition ?

Comment: I only know the definition written in Wikipedia.

Comment: The definition from Wikipedia you are using is actually the "Gateaux derivative" of $F$, which is linear and bounded in this case. You are asking whether this derivative is also the "Fréchet derivative" of $F$, which is a stronger notion of differentiability for operators. There are some known conditions under which the Gateaux and Frechet derivative coincide, I suggest you try and see whether there are any results in this area which might be of help for you.